# No Main Manifest Attribute IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have changed my project's package name. And after that, I cannot run the project jar file generating By intelliJ.

I have tried to run a jar file but it keeps saying

> no main manifest attribute in XXX.jar

which my Manifest file only contains 2 lines:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Main-Class: com.abc.program.Main

(abc is the new package name, before is def)

I have tried the following solutions that I found online:

- put the manifest folder in the resources folder
- add the Main-Class attribute, I already have one
- add the jar block to build.gradle, but intelliJ says it cannot resolve it.

Before I changed my package name, everything is good and run well, but after I changed it, I cannot run the jar anymore.

Can someone help me solve the problem please?

Comment: Does manifest contain new package name in "Main-Class"?

Comment: @y.bedrov Yes, I have changed it too. the main class is correct I think.
I can run my program inside IntelliJ, but cannot do it while running the jar.

Comment: Is it possible to share project example?

Comment: @y.bedrov Thanks for the response! I am sorry I can't share the project example. But I can run my program by using
java -cp abc.jar new_package_name.Main
It seems like that java -jar cannot identify my Manifest file?

Comment: Seems so. Is it reproducible with new sample project?

Comment: No, it is not. It is totally a new project. What I had done is changed the package name only, before that java -jar was work.